# Storage Spaces alternative but allows create storage pool from partitions instead from devices

Tags: windows, hard-disk

Currently, Windows 8 has [Storage Spaces](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831739.aspx) that allows end-users to create a storage pool from multiple devices.

However, Storage Spaces requires that the storage devices (SSD or hard disk) to be empty - meaning no partition to be created.

Are there alternatives that allows end-users to create storage pool from partitions?

Example:

Mike has 2 mechanical hard disks and 1 SSD. The SSD contains 3 partitions, where the first partition occupied by the Windows OS. The 2nd partition is occupied by another non-Windows OS - Linux OS or MacOS. The 3rd partition is a `NTFS` format. The 2 mechanical hard disks each have 2 partitions, where the first partition is a `ext3` format while the second partition is a `NTFS` format.

The Storage Spaces alternative would allows me to create storage pool from, say for example, SSD 3rd partition, 1st mechanical hard disk 1st partition and 2nd mechanical hard disk 2nd partition. Alternative, it can just form a storage pool using the `NTFS` partition from the 3 storage devices, that is, SSD 3rd partition, 1st mechanical hard disk 2nd partition and 2nd mechanical hard disk 2nd partition.

Comment: Sounds like you want a softraid controller, in case you haven't encountered that term already.